# Как валидировать группу radio button в angular?

Tags: angularstrap, angularjs

Свалидировать на обязательное заполнение:

```
<input type="radio" name="type[]" value="1" required="required">
<input type="radio" name="type[]" value="2" required="required">
<input type="radio" name="type[]" value="3" required="required">
```

Comment: Создайте эти инпуты с помощью директивы ng-input или добавьте ng-model. Оба варианта позволят scope видеть изменения этих инпутов и в контроллере или директиве можно будет делать соотвествующую валидацию.

Comment: Для всех `input` добавить `ng-model="type"`? а в контроллере как проверить на null? В шаблоне использовать `ng-show="?"`

Comment: @Jony, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**html:**

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <form name="myForm" novalidate>
        <div ng-show="myForm.type.$error.required">Type Required.</div>
        <input type="radio" name='type' ng-model="type" value="1" required>
        <input type="radio" name='type' ng-model="type" value="2" required>
        <input type="radio" name='type' ng-model="type" value="3" required>
   </form>     
</div>
```

**js:**

```
angular.module('myapp', []);
```

[Смотрите результат](http://jsfiddle.net/u9c22jnd/4/)

#### Обновление #1

С использованием `submit`.

**html:**

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="FormController" novalidate>
        <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted && myForm.type.$error.required" class="error">Types Required.</div>
        <input type="radio" name='type' ng-model="type" value="1" required>
        <input type="radio" name='type' ng-model="type" value="2" required>
        <input type="radio" name='type' ng-model="type" value="3" required>       
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>     
</div>
```

**js:**

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
    .controller('FormController', FormController);

FormController.$inject = ['$scope'];
function FormController($scope) {
    $scope.$submitted = false; // $submitted в Angular 1.3 доступно по умолчанию
    $scope.submit = function() {
        $scope.myForm.$submitted = true;
    } 
}
```

[Смотрите результат](http://jsfiddle.net/u9c22jnd/6/)

**P.S.** Не совсем понял, зачем вам массив `type[]`, потому заменил на `type`.

#### Обновление #2

**C email.**

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <form name="myForm" novalidate>
        <div ng-show="myForm.type.$error.required">Type Required.</div>
        <input type="radio" name='type' ng-model="type" value="1" required>
        <input type="radio" name='type' ng-model="type" value="2" required>
        <input type="radio" name='type' ng-model="type" value="3" required>
        <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="email" required> 
        <div ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email Required.</div>
   </form>     
</div>
```

[Смотрите результат](http://jsfiddle.net/u9c22jnd/8/)

Если необходимо, чтобы после загрузки страницы с формой не показывались ошибки, добавляем `$pristine`,т.е.

Для email:

```
 <div ng-show="!myForm.email.$pristine && myForm.email.$error.required">Email Required.</div>
```

**С email + submit.**

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="FormController" novalidate>
        <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted && myForm.type.$error.required">Type Required.</div>
        <input type="radio" name='type' ng-model="type" value="1" required>
        <input type="radio" name='type' ng-model="type" value="2" required>
        <input type="radio" name='type' ng-model="type" value="3" required> 
        <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
        <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted && myForm.email.$error.required" class="error">Email Required.</div>
  
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>     
</div>
```

[Смотрите результат](http://jsfiddle.net/u9c22jnd/7/)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Подскажите как обработать результат от AJAX? Например вывести сообщение?

Comment: @romeo код можно дополнить сообщением о невалидном e-mail

    <div class="error" ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Not valid email!</div>

Comment: @zhenyab А если кириллица будет использоваться в email-адресе? RegEx-ы тогда уж.

Comment: тогда можно перенести валидацию в контроллер и указать свою функцию, а для темплейта ничего не изменится :)

Comment: @zhenyab  именно так я и делаю в своих проектах :)

Comment: @Jony 

> обработать результат от AJAX?

А какой код у Вас на данный момент есть?

Вы получили данные через `$http.get('http://site.com/items/').success(function(){});`?

Вообще, вопросы должны быть атомарны: один вопрос - один ответ.

Comment: Сейчас у меня такой код:
 
`request.success(function (data) {
        $scope.response.type = data.type;
        $scope.response.message = data.ms;
});`  

в шаблоне HTML я пытаюсь вывести массив (но ничего не выводит):

`<span ng-repeat="error in response.message">
        {{error}}
</span>`

Comment: @Jony 

 * Что содержит `data.ms` - массив (одномерный/многомерный) или что-то ещё? Проверьте с помощью `console.log(data.ms);`

 * Вы должны присваивать значения `$scope.response.type = ...` в том же контроллере, где и форма, либо в контроллере-родителе (в том, случае, если один в другой вложен). В моём вышеприведенном примере, это `FormController`.

Answer (score 1):

В темплейте:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="type" name="type" value="1">
<input type="radio" ng-model="type" name="type" value="2">
<input type="radio" ng-model="type" name="type" value="3">

<div ng-if="type == null">
    Нужно выбрать что-нибудь
</div>
```

В контроллере:

```
$scope.type = null; // установить начальное значение, если нужно

$scope.$watch(function(){
    return $scope.type;
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    // что-нибудь сделать при изменении
});
```

Собственно такой же пример на [официальном сайте](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)

Comment: Не совсем понял, как вывести ошибку в `ng-show=""`

Comment: дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Под-вопрос один. Как описать ng-show чтобы реагировать тут же на неправильный email?

Comment: @Jony Смотрите мой ответ. Обновил для email.